# How to understand Loops and Array in java

Tags: java

I am quite confused in array loops that do have nested ones to print the Two Dimensional array. /it contains a loop without curly braces and second one has just opposite way of representing the braces for loops ...

Since i am learning I have just typed the code and got output.

```
public class TwoDimensional {
    private int i, j, k = 0;
    int[][] twod = new int[4][5];

    public void DoubleT() {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                twod[i][j] = k;
                k++;

            }
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                System.out.print(twod[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The result it generates is
0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19

Comment: Which is why it's best to always use braces. In this case, the `println()` is part of the outer loop.

Comment: Always use braces and you'll save yourself this sort of headache.

Comment: Well thanks, but can you explain how the above code works, I am not getting it though.

Comment: Did you run this through the debugger to see what is going on "under the hood"?

Comment: It did something like this

Comment: Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:9359', transport: 'socket'
0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 9 
10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:9359', transport: 'socket'

Comment: How the above loops work

Comment: Is your question about the braces or nested loops? Here's the code properly bracketed with some extra printing. Does that make it clearer? https://ideone.com/DLFT6j

Comment: nested loops, sir.

Comment: Thank you sir. It helped a lot.

Comment: Can you suggest any way to learn Array more efficiently....

Comment: Without braces the loop will consider only the first line next to it which is the tabbed line the next line is only triggered by the parent loop though this still works its still best to always use curly braces instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    public class TwoDimensional {
        private int i, j, k = 0;
        int[][] twod = new int[4][5];
    
        public void DoubleT() {
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    twod[i][j] = k;
                    k++;
                      }
                }
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                    System.out.print(twod[i][j] + " ");
                               }
                System.out.println();     
                       }
    }
```

To properly use the braces always think about the purpose of the loops you have, when do you want them to finish and when do you want them to continue.
In your case, you'll need nested loops for different tasks so you have to properly delimit each one of those tasks.

Fill the the 2D array:

```
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    twod[i][j] = k;
                    k++;
                }
           }
```

Print the 2D array values:

```
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                  for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                        System.out.print(twod[i][j] + " ");
                  }
                    System.out.println();
            }
```

Notice that, either for filling or printing the array, your first loop (iterator i) is responsible for the line. It'll stop at `I = 3`, line number 3. So you'll be in line 0 until you finish the values of all the columns on that line `( [0][0],[0][1],[0][2],[0][4] )`  and you just want to go to the second line when your first line is totally filled or printed, and so on. On the print case, you'll need to change the line before the 'i' increments (new line number) and after you have all `'j' values.

To summarize, you'll just want to increment the line ('i') or go to the next line `(println())`, when your columns `('j')` are finished.

Comment: It is better to use `twod.length` and `twod[i].length` instead of `4` and `5` in the loops.

Comment: but how to identify which is `twod.length` and which should be declared as `twod[i].length`.. Please go easy on me, I am not good at this thought.

Comment: @LearnTechWithFun `for (i = 0; i < twod.length; i++) { for (j = 0; j < twod[i].length; j++) {.....` Now if you decide to change the dimensions of `twod`, you won't have to hunt through for all the `4`s and `5`s.